# How to see tabulate/table/display of frequency that different groups take on values of a variable

Tags: variables, stata, frequency

Using Stata, suppose I have this data:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
id str5 value
1    fox
1    ox
1    cow 
2    fox
2    fox
3    ox 
3    fox
3    cow 
4    cow
4    ox
end
```

As in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702566/how-to-see-if-all-values-within-group-are-unique-identify-those-that-arent), if one wants to determine within group if the values are the same, one can use:

```
bysort id (value) : gen onevalue = value[1] == value[_N]
```

My question relates to this, but it takes it one step further. I want to know the frequencies of the combinations of `value` that `id` takes on. I do not want to consider the frequency or order within `id` - I only care if something appears at least once. This may be a little confusing, so to illustrate, I want to know something like the following:

There are three different groups that occur in the data: A) `fox, ox, cow`, B) `fox`, and C) `cow, ox`. Note that ids `1` and `3` both belong to group `A`, id `2` belongs to group `B`, and id `4` belongs to group `C`.

```
Combination    Freq
fox, ox, cow   2
fox            1
cow, ox        1
```

I do not need it in this exact format, but knowing this information would be very helpful to me. Is there a simple way to accomplish this task? The best I thought of involves creating a bunch of new variables that are indicators for whether a certain element of `value` is in `id`, and then `tab`bing all the combinations of these variables. But I feel like there should be a better way.

I would also like to be able to drop certain `id`s based on the results of above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation on @Roberto Ferrer's helpful answer. We concatenate in place, so avoiding any `reshape`. The assumption is that we are looking at a string variable. If not, apply `tostring` or `string()` first.

```
. clear

. input id str5 value

            id      value
  1. 1    fox
  2. 1    ox
  3. 1    cow 
  4. 2    fox
  5. 2    fox
  6. 3    ox 
  7. 3    fox
  8. 3    cow 
  9. 4    cow
 10. 4    ox
 11. 5    cow
 12. 5    fox
 13. 5    fox
 14. end


. bysort id (value) : gen all = value if _n == 1
(8 missing values generated)

. by id : replace all = cond(value != value[_n-1], all[_n-1] + " " + value, all[_n-1]) if  _n > 1  
(8 real changes made)

. by id : replace all = all[_N] 
(6 real changes made)

. tab all, sort 

        all |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
 cow fox ox |          6       46.15       46.15
    cow fox |          3       23.08       69.23
     cow ox |          2       15.38       84.62
        fox |          2       15.38      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         13      100.00

. egen tag = tag(id)

. tab all if tag, sort

        all |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
 cow fox ox |          2       40.00       40.00
    cow fox |          1       20.00       60.00
     cow ox |          1       20.00       80.00
        fox |          1       20.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          5      100.00


. groups id all 

  +-----------------------------------+
  | id          all   Freq.   Percent |
  |-----------------------------------|
  |  1   cow fox ox       3     23.08 |
  |  2          fox       2     15.38 |
  |  3   cow fox ox       3     23.08 |
  |  4       cow ox       2     15.38 |
  |  5      cow fox       3     23.08 |
  +-----------------------------------+
```

`groups` here is user-written to be installed by `ssc inst groups`. To count by identifier, not observations, we use `egen, tag()` to tag each identifier just once.

Another immediate trick is to apply `wordcount()`. `drop`ping identifiers conditionally on these results should now be (more) straightforward.

If the string values include spaces, use some other concatenating punctuation as appropriate, say commas, semi-colons or colons.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options.

The first one:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id str5 value
1    fox
1    ox
1    cow 
2    fox
2    fox
3    ox 
3    fox
3    cow 
4    cow
4    ox
5    cow
5    fox
5    fox
end

list, sepby(id)

*-----

// drop duplicates within -id-s
bysort id value : keep if _n == 1

// reshape
bysort id: gen j = _n
reshape wide value, i(id) j(j)

// concatenate
egen conc = concat(value*), punct(" ") // optional; -contract- takes varlist
contract conc

list
```

A second one:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id str5 value
1    fox
1    ox
1    cow 
2    fox
2    fox
3    ox 
3    fox
3    cow 
4    cow
4    ox
5    cow
5    fox
5    fox
end

list, sepby(id)

*-----

// drop duplicates within -id-s
bysort id value : keep if _n == 1

// reshape
bysort id : gen j = _n
reshape wide value, i(id) j(j)

// concatenate
egen cvalue0 = concat(value*), punct(" ")
drop value?

// reshape
reshape long cvalue, i(id) j(j)

// frequencies
bysort cvalue : gen freq = _N

// list
order cvalue
sort cvalue id
drop j
list
```

With the second option, you can `merge` the resulting information back with the original data set, if need arises.

Potentially, many variables are created with `reshape wide`, and that can be a problem depending on the size of your real data set, and your flavor of Stata.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one:

```
duplicates drop id value, force
levelsof value, local(animals) clean

gen has_ = 1
reshape wide has_*, i(id) j(value, string)

collapse (count) N=id, by(has_*)
rename has_* *

foreach beast of local animals {
    sdecode `beast', replace
    replace `beast' = cond(`beast'=="1","`beast'","")
}

egen group = concat(`animals'), punct(" ")
replace group = stritrim(group)
drop `animals'
```